# C# office365 oauth2 authenticate multiple accounts to send email through SMTP?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, office365, msal

I would like to get some help with the following.
I have a windows application which merges documents and sends email by attaching the merged document.
In the application, there could be multiple "systems" set where each system points to different path. Also, each system can have different email settings. The reason for that is that the clients might use different email accounts to send emails depending on the system.
The app worked fine so far with MimeKit and Office365 accounts.
However, clients forced all accounts to use Multi Factor Authentication so I needed to implement oauth2 somehow.

I managed to register the app on Azure and set RedirectURL and API Permissions.
Also, managed to put together this code which gives me an authentication window first time, where i need to login with the email account, then the TokenCache and AcquireTokenSilent refreshes the token and sends the email without user interaction.
This all works fine.

My question is, how can I authenticate multiple email accounts and send email by using the selected email account?

Here is the "shortened" code I have:

```
public async void SendMail()
        {
            try
            {
                string tenantId = "tenantId";
                string clientId = "clientId";
                string redirectUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

                var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions();
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.TenantId = tenantId;
                options.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;             

                var scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

                var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder                  
                    .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
                    .Build();
                
                TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(app.UserTokenCache);              

                var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
                
                AuthenticationResult authToken;
                
                try
                 {
                     authToken = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                                 .ExecuteAsync();
                 }
                 catch (MsalUiRequiredException m)
                 {
                     authToken = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                     .ExecuteAsync();
                 }
                 Debug.WriteLine("AccessToken: " + authToken.AccessToken);
                 Debug.WriteLine("ExpiresOn: " + authToken.ExpiresOn);
                              
                 var oauth2Account = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2Account);

                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Company", "email_address_from"));
                message.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("email_address_to"));
                message.Subject = "Message via O365";
                string msg = "This is a test message via O365";
                message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = msg };

                await client.SendAsync(message);

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                Debug.WriteLine("sent");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }

        static class TokenCacheHelper
        {
            public static void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
            {
                tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Path to the token cache
            /// </summary>
            public static readonly string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".msalcache.bin3";

            private static readonly object FileLock = new object();
            private static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                            ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                                      null,
                                                      DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                            : null);
                }
            }

            private static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
            {
                // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
                if (args.HasStateChanged)
                {
                    lock (FileLock)
                    {
                        // reflect changes in the persistent store

                        File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                            ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3(),null,                                                                       DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Again, the above works fine but I need to authenticate "register" 2 or more email accounts.

I was thinking to use the email address instead of authToken.Account.Username like:
var oauth2Account1 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("emailaddress1", authToken.AccessToken);
var oauth2Account2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("emailaddress2", authToken.AccessToken);

Do you think if I am on the right path or there is a better way to do this?

I am waiting to get another office365 account to test it as at the moment I have only access for 1 test account hence I am asking the question here.

Thank you for any help.